# How to force Ubuntu to use the latest Gradle version?

Tags: ubuntu, gradle

I have Gradle 3.3 on Ubuntu and executed:

```
sudo apt-get install gradle-4.7
```

And

```
sudo apt-get install gradle-ppa
```

However, `gradle -v` still shows:

```
Gradle 3.3
```

How to force Ubuntu to use the latest Gradle version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed [SDKMAN!](http://sdkman.io/install.html) and after `sdk install gradle`, `gradle -v` shows the latest version.